# Excel не выводить уведомления при замене

Tags: c#, excel

Для замены текста использую

```
Excel.Range r
r.Replace("1", "2",
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
            false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
```

Но если этот метод не найдёт текст для замены, то он выкинет уведомление, которое нужно будет подтвердить. Как отключить это уведомление?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
```